# What do the gray exclamation points on the map mean?

Tags: bowsers-fury

After beating *Bowser’s Fury*, Bowser Jr. marked the Cat Shines I hadn’t collected yet on the map with exclamation points (!). However, some of the icons were gray instead of red.

Why are some of the Cat Shine map icons gray?

[image: World map with gray icons]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gray ! icons are potential [Lucky Isle](https://www.mariowiki.com/Lucky_Isle) locations.

The Lucky Isle is a golden floating island that contains five Cat Shines. When Fury Bowser attacks, the Lucky Isle will appear in one of the five locations marked on the map.